# Do chargeable batteries break the third law of newton?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electromagnetism, momentum, batteries, electrochemistry

When you charge a lithium battery for instance the electron momentum that coming out of the source is stored in the battery. The problem is that the direction of the electron might change when connecting the battery to consumer

Comment: A battery does not store momentum. It stores energy.

Comment: @ThomasFritsch this doesn't really connected to the question it more like a semantic issues cause the momentum of electron does convert in some way

Comment: There is the same number of electrons in the battery, with the same momentum, before and after charging.

Comment: @nasu  the momentum is preserved but not the direction of the electrons coming from the source

Comment: A pendulum swings in one direction then another- does that break Newton's third law?

Comment: @MarcoOcram but when applying force on the pendulum there is force  that is applied to the opposite direction in case of electrons going to battery there isnt such force

Comment: Of course there are forces!

Comment: @MarcoOcram i dont get this answer all i ask is how come thw battery is not applying force in opposite direction when electrons hit it

Comment: Enough downvotes, guys. This question isn't worded clearly. But there is a real conceptual question here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that electrons are at rest inside a battery. Or if they move, they do so equally in all directions, so the net momentum is $0$. Also assume that they leave one battery terminal with some momentum, and arrive at the other with some momentum.

This would imply that some force inside the battery accelerates electrons as they leave and decelerates them as they arrive. Newton's laws say that there is an equal and opposite force on the battery. The battery should be accelerated in the opposite direction and the sum of forces on electrons.

Unless there are additional forces on the battery that add to this reaction force. For example, batteries are often held inside a device. Forces from the holder opposes other forces on the battery and keeps it still.

This is pretty much what happens. But keep in mind that electrons in a circuit travel at a very slow drift velocity. About $0.1$ mm/s is typical. And electrons are very light. The mass of all the electrons in an object is about $1/4000^{th}$ the total mass. And very few of the total electron participate in current. So the size of the momentum is immeasurably small.

---

The purpose of the battery is to deliver energy to distant parts of the circuit. This energy is not the kinetic energy of the electrons. It is energy derived from the electric forces that come from the charges of the electrons.

If you push extra electrons into one end of a wire, electrons become more crowded. They repel each other and spread out. This pushes some of the extra electrons down the wire. The other end of the wire is attached to the battery terminal that accepts electrons.

The battery pushes electrical energy into the circuit by crowding the electrons together against their repulsion force. The distant parts of the circuit use the energy when crowded electrons push on electrons in the circuit.

Electric forces are very strong. The amount of crowding and spreading out is very small.

Like a spring, electrons don't have to move fast to exert forces. So kinetic energy of moving down the wire (which is small) doesn't matter.

Energy from crowding per electron is measured in Volts. A 3 Volt battery squeezes electrons together less forcefully than a 10 Volt battery.

Current is electrons per second pushed into the circuit. It is measured in Amps.

Power is energy per second.

$$P = \frac{energy}{second} = \frac{energy}{electron}\frac{electrons}{second} = VA$$

There is no $1/2mv^2$ or $mv$ in this equation.

But if you are interested in conservation, just as many electrons come back as leave. They travel at the same speed. They have the same kinetic energy and momentum.

Comment: Is it means that when discharging the battery the momentum of the electrons coming out the battery would be smaller then the momentum of the electrons entering to the battery?

Comment: I see so the energy of an electron is bigger then it momentum. Is it also apply to cases of electromagnetic induction where moving magnet energy is converted to electric current?

Comment: @daniel, Electrons don't return to "+" terminal of the battery any more slowly than they depart from the "-" terminal. Think of the electrons moving around a circuit as being like a belt that transmits power from one pulley to one or more other pulleys in a machine. The speed of the belt is the same everywhere. The energy isn't transmitted by the kinetic energy of the belt's molecules, it's transmitted by the _tension_ in the belt. The tension is greatest in the segment that is pulled by the driving wheel, it's least in the segment that is leaving the driving wheel, etc.